# Going out of the loop without using the break command

Tags: c

I wrote a program for finding gcd; it works well. However, using `break` is banned for assignment. What else can I do to exit the loop? I tried to change the condition of the `while` loop but it printed out wrong answers.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int i, gcd, min, arr[100];

    gcd = min;


    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {

          while(1)
            {
                if(gcd % min ==0  && arr[i] % min== 0)
                        break;
                min --;
            }
    }


    gcd = min;

    printf("\n gcd= %d",gcd);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See the `1` in `while (1)`? In that place, you can put a condition for continuing the loop. Your test in the `if` statement is currently a condition for ending the loop. Change it to a condition for continuing the loop and move it to the `while` in place of the `1`.

Comment: Get out of the habit of putting new-line characters before a message instead of after, as you have in `printf("\n gcd= %d",gcd);`. C was designed to have new-line characters at the ends of lines. It causes output to be sent immediately to interactive devices instead of held in a buffer.

Comment: FYI, your program cannot be working as shown, since `min`, `n`, and `arr` are never initialized. When preparing code for future questions, prepare a [mre] that includes complete code that can be compiled and executed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You should revise your code to use the oldest algorithm, [Euclid's GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).  It is dramatically more efficient than what you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your break condition as the while loop execution condition:

```c
for(i=1; i<n; i++){
   while(!(gcd % min == 0 && arr[i] % min == 0)){                  
       min --;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can switch the 1 inside `while(1)` with a variable and switch it's value in the if statement also make sure you define or set n to a variable as it was unknown when i tested your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 #define n 10
int main(){

 int i, gcd, min, arr[100],verification=1;

 gcd = min;


    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        verification = 1;
          while(verification)
            {
                if(gcd % min ==0  && arr[i] % min== 0)
                        verification = 0;
                        if (verification)
                        min --;


            }


    }

 gcd= min;

printf("\n gcd= %d",gcd);


return 0;
}
```